# "Раззудись плечо, размахнись рука"

Tags: этимология, пунктуация

У А. Кольцова есть стихотворение "Косарь", строчка из которого стала более популярной, чем само стихотворение: "Раззудись плечо, размахнись рука".
Меня тут интересуют две вещи. Во-первых, почему "раззудись"? Зуд - это чесотка, насколько я понимаю. А во-вторых, нужно ли выделять запятыми "обращение" к плечу и руке?

Answer (score 1):

Поэт Кольцов чуть переосмыслил прямое физическое значение глагола *зудеть* (свербеть, чесаться). Зуд как синоним нетерпения, побуждения наверняка и другие писатели использовали.

> А. А. Григорьев. Мои литературные и нравственные скитальчества (1862)
> Настоящей страстности в нем не было, но зато был постоянный **неугомонный зуд страстности**, и зудил же он, зудил себя паче меры ― и стихами, и прозой, и разными любвями...

Повелительное наклонение глаголов  требует постановки запятых перед  обращениями, хотя бы и неодушевленными. А у поэта именно повелительное, а не сослагательное наклонение в стихах. Ср : *зазвучи песня погромче, непременно ударился бы в пляс*.